# neo4j python language driver

Tags: python, neo4j

I'm trying the example from the neoj4 website for the Python driver. The issue is that I keep getting an IndentionError

I have tried spaces vs tabs. doesn't solve it. With in this simple file I did a:

```
def print_this(str):
  print(str)
  return;

print_this('a simple test')
```

and that worked fine.

```
from neo4j.v1 import GraphDatabase

uri = "bolt://localhost:7687"
driver = GraphDatabase.driver(uri, auth=("neo4j", "password"))

def print_friends_of(tx, name):
    for record in tx.run("MATCH (a:Person)-[:KNOWS]->(f) "
                         "WHERE a.name = {name} "
                         "RETURN f.name", name=name):
    print(record["f.name"])

with driver.session() as session:
    session.read_transaction(print_friends_of, "Alice")
```

The error

```
print(record["f.name"])
    ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block
```

Anybody any idea?

Tanks

Comment: your "for" statement and "print" statement are at the same level which is why you are getting that error. Since the "print" statement is supposed to be inside "for" it is giving you that error.

Comment: Good point but it doesn't work. Than I got a Syntax error. The example comes from the official Neoj4 website. I do assume that they have tested it. https://neo4j.com/docs/api/python-driver/current/ But I can't get it to work.

Comment: What error do you get after indenting the print properly?
I don't get any error after indentation changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the statement

```
for record in tx.run("MATCH (a:Person)-[:KNOWS]->(f) "
                     "WHERE a.name = {name} "
                     "RETURN f.name", name=name):
```

you are starting a new `for` loop. Your next line should be indented so it is inside that `for` loop. Change it to

```
for record in tx.run("MATCH (a:Person)-[:KNOWS]->(f) "
                         "WHERE a.name = {name} "
                         "RETURN f.name", name=name):
    print(record["f.name"]) #note how it is indented to be inside of the for loop
```

Comment: Thank You Solved it ;-)